# Adding instances behind multiple LoadBalancers in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to figure out a way to add a ec2 node to two load balancers, but am not finding a sane way to do it. I would think that the below code would allow me to do this, but am not getting my expected results

Please note that this code is HIGHLY stripped down to just show the LB portion.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": " App Demo / Jd / 01042016",
  "Parameters": {
    "LoadBalancers": {
      "Description": "Please refer the LoadBalancerNames which you want the instances to be registered to",
      "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::LoadBalancers::LoadBalancerNames>",
      "Default": "web-app-demo-ext,web-api-demo-ext"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "AppAutoScalingGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZones": {
          "Ref": "AZs"
        },
        "LoadBalancerNames": [{
          "Ref": "LoadBalancers"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect to see a list which I can add multiple LBs to, but I am instead seeing a normal input box (string)

Adding in images with some firebug hackery....

Expected Results
[image: Expected Results]

What actually happens
[image: What I actually get]

**UPDATE**

After fudging with Cloud Designer, I believe that `"Type": "List<AWS::EC2::LoadBalancers::LoadBalancerNames>"` is incorrect and should really be `"Type": "List<AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer>"`

This still does not propagate as a list though

Comment: Try removing the "Default" from your parameter.

Comment: @MattHouser didn't work

Comment: Where did your "expected results" come from?

Comment: @MattHouser I just created what I expected it to look like after manipulating the DOM tree of something that already existed and works

Comment: @MattHouser it was specifically this snippet I modified for AZs that works http://pastebin.ca/3318004

Comment: I don't think `List<AWS::EC2::LoadBalancers::LoadBalancerNames>` is a valid parameter type. It's not listed under the data types for the `Type` property: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Comment: @MattHouser yeah i had updated my question around that.

Comment: Even `List<AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer>` isn't in the list of available types. I don't see any appropriate type for picking load balancers.

Comment: Look at ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html

Comment: `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer` is valid for a resource type. But a `List<AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer>` is not valid for a parameter type.

Comment: @MattHouser see my answer below on how I solved it. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't give you the UI you were looking for, but it will allow you to specify multiple load balancer names in a single parameter.

Use `CommaDelimitedList` as the parameter type.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": " App Demo / Jd / 01042016",
  "Parameters": {
    "LoadBalancers": {
      "Description": "Please refer the LoadBalancerNames which you want the instances to be registered to",
      "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Default": "web-app-demo-ext,web-api-demo-ext"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "AppAutoScalingGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZones": {
          "Ref": "AZs"
        },
        "LoadBalancerNames": {
          "Ref": "LoadBalancers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You will need multiple references. And the reason is because the `"LoadBalancerNames"` key can take multiple references, like so: `"LoadBalancerNames": { "Foo", "Bar" }`

Really hope this helps someone else as it had me scratching my head for days :)

```
{
  ................
  "Parameters": {
    .......
    "LoadBalancerApp": {
      "Description": "Please refer the LoadBalancerNames (APP) which you want the instances to be registered to",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "web-app-demo-ext"
    },
    "LoadBalancerApi": {
      "Description": "Please refer the LoadBalancerNames (API) which you want the instances to be registered to",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "web-api-demo-ext"
    },
    .......
  },
  "Resources": {
    ........
    "AppnameAutoScalingGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZones": {
          "Ref": "AZs"
        },
        "LaunchConfigurationName": {
          "Ref": "AppnameLaunchConfig"
        },
        "LoadBalancerNames": [{
          "Ref": "LoadBalancerApp"
        }, {
          "Ref": "LoadBalancerApi"
        }],
    ..........
}
```

Comment: Did this give you the same UI you mentioned in your question?